# how to split a string by characters which occur in another list?

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split a string as soon as I see a symbol which is in my symbol list (it's quite a big list) . now something that I want to know ,as a new python user , is there a method not the split method , which I can tell it to split as soon as it sees any memeber to the symbolList? 
here is an example:

```
symbolList=[',' , '&' , '8' , '9' , '.']
words = ['ha,di' , 'dea&r']
for word in words :
    for i in word :
         if i in symbolList:
             #a method which splits the string by the symbol
```

I want to have and out put like :

```
newWords=['ha' , 'di' , 'dea' ,'r']
```

Comment: Are the items in `symbolList` always one character long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `rsplit`

```
words = ['ha,di' , 'dea&r','1.2']
for i in words:
    print re.split(',|&|8|9|\.', i)

#output

['ha', 'di']
['dea', 'r']
['1', '2']
```

for very big list

```
import re
symbolList=[',' , '&' , '8' , '9' , '.']
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, symbolList))

words = ['ha,di' , 'dea&r','1.2']
for i in words:
    print re.split(regex, i)
```

Comment: thank you , it seems to work but as I mentioned the symbol list is a very big list which will not be easy to use it like this , that's why I'm asking if there are any other options .

Comment: @Singu try now with this

Comment: You can also use `regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, symbolList))`.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар thank you , just some minutes and I'll give you feedback.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар it's perfect. But using this I'm facing a bigger problem , which leads to a typeError : unhashable type . when I try to save word=re.split(regex, i) and send this word in another for cycle .

Comment: @Singu thats due to r u sending a list as regex.please try to print regex . is it string or array

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар regex is a unicode because I'm working on utf-8 texts .

Comment: @Singu please add a sample data regex . which is codec

Comment: `|\،|\;|\«|\؛|\؟|\!|\"|\.\.|\)|\(|\+|\*|\-|\.|1|0|3|2|5|4|7|6|9|8|\»|\:|\<|\>|\ـ|4\-|\×|90|\[|\]|\\|\٪|\٬|\﷼|\۱|\۰|\۳|\۲|\۵|\۴|\۷|\۶|\۹|\۸|\{|\}|\|` this is my printed regex and when I try `print type(regex)` the output is unicode

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way to use the regrex in a loop for each for not for the whole list , it will solve the problem. a loop like : `for word in words : for i in word : s=re.split(regrex,i) `

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list of words into a string, then replace all delimiters with a common delimiter say `,` and now run a split on `,`

```
symbolList=[',' , '&' , '8' , '9' , '.']             
words = ['ha,di' , 'dea&r']                          
delimiter = symbolList[0]        #Any symbol in symbolList                    
words_str = delimiter.join(words) #converting words to a string separated by delimiter
print words_str
for symbol in symbolList:   #replace other symbols with delimiters
    words_str = words_str.replace(symbol,delimiter)  
print words_str
print words_str.split(delimiter)
```

**output**

```
ha,di,dea&r
ha,di,dea,r
['ha', 'di', 'dea', 'r']
```

Comment: Thank you. i'm going to try it now!